# Поиск в объекте

Tags: java

Всем привет. Такой вопрос. У меня простая задача. Создать класс данных о человеке (любых). В этот класс отправляются данные(String/int/boolean) через конструктор.
У меня задача организовать поиск людей по имени или по возрасту. И выдать где совпало. Реализация в отдельном методе. 
Как решить проблему ? 
Создать многомерный массив и запустить данные? Соответственно int заранее перевести в String?

```
public class Patient {

private String name;
private String secondName;
private String diagnosis;
private int age;
private boolean stateOfHealth; // true - здоров


Patient(String secondName, String name, String diagnosism, int age, boolean stateOfHealth) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
    this.name = name;
    this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    this.age = age;
    this.stateOfHealth = stateOfHealth;
}

public void information() {
    System.out.println("Фамилия пациента: " + secondName);
    System.out.println("Имя пациента: " + name);
    System.out.println("Диагноз: " + diagnosis);
    System.out.println("Возрост: " + age);
    if (stateOfHealth)
    System.out.println("Состояние: здоров");
    else System.out.println("Состояние: нездоров");
}

String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}

int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void seek(int i) {

}

public void seek(String str) {

}
```

}

Comment: непонятна в чем проблема. приложите к вопросу ваш класс и как храните данные

Comment: Пользователи вводит имя или возраст, и как сравнивать или искать? 
вся информация же храниться в переменных типа "пациент".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя искать пациентов в классе пациент. В этом классе есть информация только об одном пациенте. Искать нужно в классе "Список пациентов"

```
class PatientList extends ArrayList<Patient> {
  // Ищем пациента, удолетворяющего некторому критерию
  private Patient search(Predicate<Patient> test) {
    for (Patient p : this) {
      if (test.test(p))  // проверяем критерий
        // если удовлетворяет - возвращаем найденный объект
        return p;
    }
    // если ничего не нашли, вернем null
    return null;
  }

  public Patient searchByAge(int age) {
    return search((p) -> return p.getAge() == age);
  }

  public Patient searchBySecondName(String secondName) {
    return search((p) -> return p.getsecondName().equals(secondName));
  }
}
```

Работа

```
// Создаем список пациентов
PatientList list = new PatientList();
// Заполняем его
list.add(new Patient(......));
list.add(new Patient(......));
...........
list.add(new Patient(......));
..........
// Ищем по возрасту 21 год
Patient p = list.searchByAge(21);
if (p != null)  // если нашли - выводим информацию
  p.information();
else
  System.out.println("Nothing");
```

Comment: Привет. Я только начал изучать язык, как этот метод будет вызываться в основном классе?

Comment: @Константин Расширил ответ

Comment: Как я вижу у вас лямбда, а мне до нее как пешком до Китая, да и код у вас слишком сложный для новичка (

Comment: @Константин если решение вашей задачи вам, как новичку, кажется сложным, то это вы взялись за слишком сложные для вас задачи, а не код слишком сложный объективно. Занимайтесь пока более простыми вещами, что там делают новички: пишут хелло ворды, пузырьковые сортировки и **читают книжки**, чтобы когда-нибудь понимать больше, чем нивички (и даже лямбды)

Comment: Вы за две недели научились идеально владеть ArrayList и лямбда + обобщением ? Нет. Так зачем пытаетесь обидеть?

Comment: @Константин Вы не поверите, но да. И где Вас обидели? Послали читать книжки? Это, нынче, обида?

Comment: При чем тут обида? У меня задание написать код не используя эти темы, ибо лектор их просто не читал.
Спасибо, что подсказали на счет ArrayList. Вопрос решен.

Comment: @Константин Ну вы же сами пишете `зачем пытаетесь обидеть?` Вот я и пытаюсь понять где Вас обидели. Про то, что это очередная лаба и, что нельзя использовать какие-то возможности языка, в исходном вопросе ни слова

Comment: @Константин Stack Overflow — это сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию, где знатоки рассказывают каким образом решить задачу *оптимальным путем*: ограничения наложенные преподавателем не являются для нас критерием эффективности. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его верным. Если у вас появились новые вопросы, например, о лямбдах, пожалуйста, задайте их отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать просто:

```
public class Patient {

private static ArrayList<Patient> allPatients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
private String name;
private String secondName;
private String diagnosis;
private int age;
private boolean stateOfHealth; // true - здоров



public Patient(String secondName, String name, String diagnosism, int age, boolean stateOfHealth) {

    this.secondName = secondName;
    this.name = name;
    this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    this.age = age;
    this.stateOfHealth = stateOfHealth;
    allPatients.add(this);
}

 public static ArrayList<Patient> getAllPatients() {
    return allPatients;
}


public static ArrayList<Patient> seek(int age) {

    ArrayList<Patient> chosenPatients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

    for (Patient patient: allPatients) {
        if(patient.age == age){
            chosenPatients.add(patient);
        }
    }return chosenPatients;
}

public static ArrayList<Patient> seek(String str) {

    ArrayList<Patient> chosenPatients = new ArrayList<Patient>();

    for (Patient patient: allPatients) {
        if(patient.name.equals(str)){
            chosenPatients.add(patient);
        }
    }return chosenPatients;
}
```

Comment: Вообще такие методы лучше добавлять  в отдельный класс,  например PatientController